# Session_status - the real usage

Tags: php, session

I' cant fully understand the real usage of the *session_status* function. I know that it checks whenever the session engine is even enabled and if it's the case if we just have started the session mechanism in the script using *session_start* function. But it's rather useless in my opinion because in almost all scripts I've seen so far the code that make use of session just calls session_start at the start of the script and to check if a variable was already saved we use *isset($_SESSION[var_name])* and checking for *PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE* value is useless since we just always call *session_start* if we would like to use session and check if the variable just have been stored?

Answer (score 1):

session_start() is typically used as reported in the first answer above.  But, the same php file containing that "session_start();" statement might become and "include" or "require" file in a different program.  In that case the "session_start();" might be rejected because a prior "session_start();" exists in the program that contains the "include/require".  session_status provides the answer and determines if a "session_start();" is needed.

You could in most cases just use "session_id();" and if none exists follow that with a "session_start();"

Answer (score 0):

One reason to use session_status seems to be that it makes it possible to check whether sessions are **enabled at all** on the current site.

From the documentation:

> - PHP_SESSION_DISABLED if sessions are disabled.
> - PHP_SESSION_NONE if sessions are enabled, but none exists.
> - PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE if sessions are enabled, and one exists.

Comment: so it just checks if we have called _session_start_ in the script?

Comment: I'm guessing it checks if you are even able to call session_start in the first place. If PHP_SESSION_DISABLED is true/active you probably can't even create a session so you could check before for that before trying to start one.